# Building Interactive games for video calls in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, video, agora.io

I'm trying to create a react-native video call app using agora.io and was looking to create some interactive games that users can play on the call like the ones that Facebook messenger offers. Are there any resources out there that I can refer to or any tutorials? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can check out the following links to help you get started with adding Agora.io RTE SDK to your react native project.

[Agora React-Native Quickstart](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RN-Quickstart)

[React-Native API reference](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/react_native/index.html)

You can also read up about [how you can build games in react-native](https://dev.to/ryanvanbelkum/building-a-mobile-game-using-react-native-3320).